# Reference delegate type

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Why does this program show an error for using seq:

```
class Program
{
    delegate double Sequence(int r);

    void F(ref Sequence seq) // Here
    {
        Sequence seq2 = r =>
        {
            if (r % 2 == 0)
                return seq(r); // Here
            else
                return seq(2 * r); // Here
        };
        seq = seq2;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

> Error CS1628  Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'seq' inside an
>   anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local
>   function  CsharpRefLambdaTest

The problem is with that the parameter `seq` is a reference type. But why is it wrong? what't the problem with a reference `seq`? If `seq` is not reference the program has no errors.

Is there any way to correct the program while keeping seq as a reference?

The program is just an test and it is not going to do anything.

================

I need to use the value of `seq` to define a new Sequence `seq2` and then assign `seq = seq2`. But the values of seq are not usable. If the values of `seq` are not going to be usable why does C# allow `seq` to be a reference at all?

===============================

**Edit:**

The program above is just simplified version of the following:

```
class Program
{
    delegate double Sequence(int r);

    Sequence G(Sequence seq)
    {
        Sequence seq2 = r =>
        {
            if (r % 2 == 0)
                return seq(r);
            else
                return seq(2 * r);
        };
        return seq2;
    }

    void F(ref Sequence seq)
    {
        seq = G(seq);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why I cannot remove `G` and instead add the defining code of `G inside`F`.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with reference _types_; the problem is the `ref` parameter.  You don't need that; don't use it.

Comment: @SLaks This is a simplified program. In fact I'm going to change seq in F. But the error prevents.

Comment: @nano if that is what you want, it would be better to *return* the composed lambda - i.e. `Sequence F(Sequence seq) { ... }` with a `return`

Comment: You will need to wrap it in something that can carry it then, add it as a property to a carry-type, one that simply exists to carry the value across method calls, and allow this property to have a setter, then it can be changed. As the error states, you cannot use `ref` like this with local functions or delegates.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen or simply `return` it :)

Comment: It would be nice to know what the error message says, please edit your post to give us a clue. Your code doesn't do anything. `F` takes a reference type by reference. You never call `F`, and you don't reassign `seq` within `F` (what you'd expect for a parameter passed byref). Instead, all `F` does is declare and initialize another `Sequence` delegate instance, which quickly goes out of scope and becomes garbage. What are you trying to achieve? What did you expect your code to do? Why are you using `ref` in the function signature?

Comment: "But I don't understand why I cannot" once again: because the compiler needs to protect against a very specific - and very bad - scenario that would be possible if you *could* do that.

Comment: btw; there is a workaround: snapshot; i.e. `var tmp = seq; ...` and capture `tmp` instead of `seq` (i.e. `return tmp(r);` instead of `return seq(r);` -  then update `seq` *outside* of the lambda.

Comment: @Flydog57 I think now it is clear what the simplified code is going to do. It is to to change `seq` based on the `seq` valued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error message here is: "CS1628  Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'seq' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function"  - `seq2` is the lambda expression; it has nothing to do with reference types, but rather: lifetimes. You could, after all, call it like:

```
void Foo() {
    Sequence bar = SomeMethod; // bar is a LOCAL of Foo
    F(ref bar);
    // not shown: perhaps do something with bar, perhaps not
}
```

at which point, `F` would need to somehow create a lambda that contains within it a reference to a position on the stack (a reference to the local `bar`). Now note that this lambda, being an object, could outlive `Foo`, and `bar` would be an undefined - and possibly reused - memory location.

So: you can't "capture" parameters that are passed as `ref`, `in` our `out`, where I'm using "capture" loosely here to mean "use within the scope of a lambda or anonymous method that forms an expression-tree, delegate expression; or within an iterator block or async continuation".

Just remove the `ref`. You don't need it, and it isn't helping. If your intention is to *change* the delegate, then consider instead *returning* the composed delegate.

---

as an alternative workaround: snapshot the value and capture the snapshot:

```
void F(ref Sequence seq)
{
    var tmp = seq;
    seq = r =>
    {
        if (r % 2 == 0)
            return tmp(r);
        else
            return tmp(2 * r);
    };
}
```

this avoids the problematic scenario because the snapshot *dereferences* the `ref` parameter, meaning: there is now no possibility that we're capturing a stack location.

Comment: I need to use the value of `seq` to define a new `Sequence` `seq2` and then assign `seq = seq2`. But the values of `seq` are not usable.

Comment: @nano like I said: `return` it instead of using `ref`; or as someone else said: use an object with fields or properties where you can put it. The problem here is stack semantics and avoiding the possibility of capturing a ref local

Comment: in fact I can use a copy of `seq` to define `seq2`.

Comment: @nano like in bit under the horizontal line, then?

Comment: I can remove `G` function in my second code and use a copy of `seq` to define `seq2`. This is what `G` does.